# Vue JS + Firestore - Link computed property to single document field

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new on Vue JS and dbs like Firebase and I'm having some trouble with what I'd like to do.

Here is the idea: I have repeated components ('**LaundryMachine.vue**') which each have a boolean property (computed property) **available**.

I want users to be able to change the state of these components. The change is sent to the Firestore DB and the app needs to read the data from the DB.

I have been able link the VueJS code and the DB and edit the DB data within the app. I have however not been successful at reading the data from the DB.

**More precisely**, I have only been able to read the data from one or several documents of the DB and log at the console. But i can't manage to link the data to properties.

Here is what I have on the LaundryMachine.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h2>Machine {{ this.machineNum }}</h2>
    <img src="../assets/washing_machine.png" /><br />
    <v-btn v-bind:color="buttonColor" v-on:click="changeAvailability">
      {{ this.availability }}</v-btn
    >
    <v-btn v-bind:color="buttonColor" v-on:click="editState">Edit state</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import db from './firebaseInit.js';

  export default {
    name: 'LaundryMachine',
    props: {
      name: String,
      machineNum: Number,
      residenceNum: Number,
    },
    methods: {
      editState: function(event) {
        console.log('available:' + this.available);

        // Emit to parent component which succesfully edits the fields in the DB
        this.$emit('update-availability', this.machineNum, this.residenceNum);

        // This part is just about logging out on the console the db documents data which works fine

        db.collection('Machines')
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              console.log(doc.id + doc.data() + doc.data().available);
            });
          });
      }
    },
    computed: {
      available: function() {

        // This is where I want to link my computed property to the db document field but which doesn't work. If i print {{this.available}}, i'll get an undefined

        let ref = db
          .collection('Machines')
          .doc('machine' + this.residenceNum + this.machineNum);
        ref.get().then(snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.exists) {
            ref.get().then(snapshot => {
              return snapshot.data().available;
            });
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        });
      },
      availability: function() {
        if (this.available) {
          return 'disponible';
        } else {
          return 'indisponible';
        }
      },
      buttonColor: function() {
        if (this.available) {
          return 'primary';
        } else {
          return 'red';
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

This is honestly really frustrating as I'm able to log on the console the fields of the data base but I can't link them to my "available" computed property. I've looked through a lot of posts and firestore doc and I can't find something which works.

Thanks in advance !